# Complicated generic typing for Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to understand how to make a function type-safe, but have not been able to do it. The function should take in an object and return a number. Here's a *very* simple example (for my actual application, the interfaces are more complex).

```
interface Parent {
  id: number;
  children: Child[];
}

interface Child {
  text: string;
}

const parents: Parent[] = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    children: [
      {text: 'Child 1a'}, {text: 'Child 1b'}, 
      {text: 'Child 1c'}, {text: 'Child 1d'}, 
      {text: 'Child 1e'}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    children: [
      {text: 'Child 2a'}, {text: 'Child 2b'}, {text: 'Child 2c'}
    ]
  }  
];

function getMaxNumChildren<T>(data: T[], childKey: keyof T) {
  return data.reduce((max: number, parent: T) => {
    return max > parent[childKey].length ? max : parent[childKey].length;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(getMaxNumChildren<Parent>(parents, 'children')); // 5
```

So, as you can imagine, `parent[childKey].length` throws an error because typescript doesn't actually know that `T[keyof T]` is an array.

I've tried casting to `any[]`, among other random things, but I can't seem to get this right and keep the function purely generic. Any ideas?

Comment: As long as you're certain that ```childKey``` will always point to an array, you could cast ```parent``` as an Array: ```(parent[childKey] as Array<any>).length```.  Or you could do a type check to make sure ```length``` exists before running the reduce. Or maybe defining a parent type that ```T``` extends which has an Array indexed with a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I can imagine getting this to work is to make the function generic in `K`, the type of `childKey`, and annotating that `data` is an array of objects with keys in `K` and properties with a numeric `length` property, like this:

```
function getMaxNumChildren<K extends keyof any>(
  data: Array<Record<K, { length: number }>>,
  childKey: K
) {
  return data.reduce((max, parent) => {
    return max > parent[childKey].length ? max : parent[childKey].length;
  }, 0);
}
```

The compiler is then able to verify that `parent[childkey]` has a numeric `length` and there are no errors.  Then you call it like this:

```
console.log(getMaxNumChildren(parents, 'children')); // 5
```

Note that you don't call `getMaxNumChildren<Parent>(...)` anymore because the generic type is the key type, not the object type.  You *could* call `getMaxNumChildren<"children">(...)` if you want, but I'd just let type inference work for you here.

---

Hope that works for you.  If it doesn't work for your use case, please consider editing the question to include more details.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-kIx3O11MQjZZAABhFRjwpnMJkZTpM+kx7y+P3+1EBWExfrsOUStp4iRFMeQAHoK8gAKxAA)

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are over-complicating it. Just use a Parent array</s>

```
function getMaxNumChildren<T>(data: Parent[]T[], keyGetter: (obj: T) => Array<unknown>) {
  return data.reduce((max: number, parent: ParentT) => {
    return Math.max > (keyGetter(parent.children).length ?, max : parent.children.length;);
  }, 0);
}
```

---

#### Updated answer

Better to use a callback than abusing the type system.

```
function getMaxNumChildren<T>(data: T[], keyGetter: (obj: T) => Array<unknown>) {
  return data.reduce((max: number, parent: T) => {
    return Math.max(keyGetter(parent).length, max);
  }, 0);
}
```

You use it like this:

```
console.log(getMaxNumChildren<Parent>(parents, (p) => p.children));
```

Comment: If that was the only interface I had to interact with, then yes, this would be easy. But I need to do this in multiple places in my app with various objects that aren't alike at all. So the `getMaxNumChildren` function needs to be generic.

Comment: @exk0730 I see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let TypeScript know about two generic types, not just one. The first being some key and the second being some object where that key has a value of an array.

Try something like this:

```
function getMaxNumChildren<TKey extends string, TObj extends { [key in TKey]: unknown[] }>(data: TObj[], childKey: TKey) {
    // ...
}
```